# Por que as classes pull-left e pull-right não estão funcionando mais no Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

Estou atualizando o código para a atual versão [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/) e estava na versão Bootstrap 3.

Atualizei os arquivos CSS, JS, e outros. Ocorreu que não estão mais funcionando algumas partes. Essas são, por exemplo as que estão com as classes `pull-right` e `pull-left`.

Isso ocorre com outras partes do site também. Já revisei o CSS e mesmo assim, não encontrei o motivo. Isso é algum problema com o Bootstrap?

```
<div class="navbar-header pull-left">
    <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">
        <small>
            <img src="/logo.png" width="30px">Site
        </small>
     </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As classes `pull-right` e `pull-left` **não funcionam mais no Bootstrap v4 porque foram removidas**.

> *Added .float-{sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none} classes for responsive floats **and removed .pull-left and .pull-right** since they’re redundant to .float-left and .float-right*.

---

Existe um link do próprio Bootstrap que mostra as [mudanças](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/) que ocorreram para a versão 4.

> O Bootstrap 4 é uma grande reescrita de quase todo o projeto. As mudanças mais notáveis são resumidas imediatamente abaixo, seguidas de mudanças específicas de classe e comportamento em componentes relevantes.

No caso das classes comentadas [`.pull-left`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#utilities) e [`.pull-right`](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#utilities) elas foram substituídas por outras classes, respectivamente `.float-left` e `.float-right`.

Além disso, elas foram incrementadas com os tamanhos de *grid* ao qual permite adicionar os tamanhos desejados, por exemplo `.float-xs-right` ou `.float-sm-left` e/ou outros relacionados. Não é necessário determinar um tamanho para cada elemento, é somente uma funcionalidade específica que pode ajudar em alguns casos.

Nesse caso da barra de navegação, você vai substituir os `.pull` pela atual correspondente `.float`:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navbar-header float-left">
        <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">
            <small>
                <img src="/logo.png" width="30px">Site
            </small>
         </a>
    </div>
```

---

Veja também no *snippet* abaixo que se tentar adicionar a classe `.pull-*` não funciona como esperado, devido a remoção do mesmo na versão do Bootstrap 4:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navbar-header pull-right">
        <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">
            <small>
                <img src="/logo.png" width="30px">Texto com classe pull-right
            </small>
         </a>
    </div>
```

Diferente do `.float-*`:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="navbar-header float-right">
        <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">
            <small>
                <img src="/logo.png" width="30px">Texto com classe float-right
            </small>
         </a>
    </div>
```

Interessante que você leia o [*changelog* de mudanças](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/) completo para saber como migrar corretamente um projeto para a versão 4 do Bootstrap.